# How to replace outer curly brackets with outer square brackets using JOLT

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

How to replace outer curly brackets with outer square brackets for field `filters` using JOLT transformation?

```
{
   "after":{
      "import_id":912,
      "date":"2021-01-21 00:00:00.0",
      "filters":"{{{NeverCheckSupplier: {supplier: 5}}, {NeverCheckSupplier: {supplier: 5}}}",
      "entries":"{1952253,1952252,1952251}",
      "commit_time":"2021-01-21 13:20:48.630796",
      "id":1
   },
   "table":"commits",
   "op_type":"c"
}
```

Desired output

```
{
  "after" : {
    "import_id" : 912,
    "date" : "2021-01-21 00:00:00.0",
    "filters" : "[{NeverCheckSupplier: {supplier: 5}}, {NeverCheckSupplier: {supplier: 5}}]",
    "entries" : "{1952253,1952252,1952251}",
    "commit_time" : "2021-01-21 13:20:48.630796",
    "id" : 1
  },
  "table" : "commits",
  "op_type" : "c"  
}
```

Comment: Your input is not a valid JSON. Please put a valid input and it's better to add a desired output to your question.

Comment: It is a valid json. if you are talking about value of "filters" field - it's a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can successively use ***split***, ***join*** and ***concat*** functions within a **modify** transformation, and then get rid of auxiliary attributes through use of **remove** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "fl0": "=split('\\{\\{',@(1,filters))",
        "fl1": "=join('',@(1,fl0))",
        "fl2": "=split('\\}\\}\\}',@(1,fl1))",
        "fl3": "=join('',@(1,fl2))",
        "filters": "=concat('[',@(1,fl3),'}}]')"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "fl*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```